# I have my code but is not fetching the data from my json file

Tags: json, angular, fetch

I have my code but is not fetching the data from my JSON file I keep getting 0 arguments to wonder what I am doing wrong on my code can someone help I am using angular for this project.

I have my code but is not fetching the data from my JSON file I keep getting 0 arguments to wonder what I am doing wrong on my code can

****Code****

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Flight } from './flight';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  [x: string]: any;

  url: string = '/assets/data/flights.json';

  Constructor(){
    this.getFlights();
  }

  allArrivals: Flight[] = [];
  allDepartures: Flight [] = [];
  filteredArrivals: Flight []=[];
  filteredDepartures: Flight [] = [];

  arrivalText: string = "arrival";
  departureText: string = "departure";

  showArrivals: boolean = true;


  getFlights(): void {
    // fetch flight data from JSON file
    fetch(this.url).then((res) => {
      res.json().then((json) => {
        // for each flight in the JSON data, create a new Flight instance
        json.forEach((flight: any) => {
          let newFlight = new Flight(flight.airline, flight.flightNo, flight.origin, flight.departure, flight.destination, flight.arrival);
          newFlight.gate = flight.gate;
          newFlight.status = flight.status;


          // check if the destination includes "Chattanooga" and add to corresponding array
          if (newFlight.destination.includes("Chattanooga")) {
            this.allArrivals.push(newFlight);
          } else {
            this.allDepartures.push(newFlight);
          }
        });
    

        // set the filtered arrays to the all arrays
        this.filteredArrivals = [...this.allArrivals];
        this.filteredDepartures = [...this.allDepartures];
      });

    });

  }

  filterFlights(keyword: string): void {
      keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();
      let matchingArrivals: Flight[] = [];
      for(let i=0; i < this.allArrivals.length; i++) {
          let flight = this.allArrivals[i];
          let flightInfo = (flight.airline + flight.flightNo + flight.origin + flight.status).toLowerCase();
          if (flightInfo.indexOf(keyword) >= 0) {
              matchingArrivals.push(flight);
          }
      }
      this.filteredArrivals = [...matchingArrivals];
      let matchingDepartures: Flight[] = [];
      for(let i=0; i < this.allDepartures.length; i++) {
          let flight = this.allDepartures[i];
          let flightInfo = (flight.airline + flight.flightNo + flight.destination + flight.status).toLowerCase();
          if (flightInfo.indexOf(keyword) >= 0) {
              matchingDepartures.push(flight);
          }
      }
      this.filteredDepartures = [...matchingDepartures];
  }

  resetFlights(): void {
      this.filteredArrivals = [...this.allArrivals];
      this.filteredDepartures = [...this.allDepartures];
  }

}
```

```
export class Flight {
  airline: string;
  flightNo: string;
  origin: string;
  departure: string;
  destination: string;
  arrival: string;
  gate: string;
  status: string;

  constructor(airline: string, flightNo: string, origin: string, departure: string,
        destination: string, arrival: string ){
    this.airline = airline;
    this.flightNo = flightNo;
    this.origin = origin;
    this.departure = departure;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.arrival = arrival;
    this.gate = "";
    this.status = "";

  }
    
  isCancelled(): boolean {
    return this.status.toLowerCase() === "cancelled";
  }
        
  isDelayed(): boolean {
    return this.status.toLowerCase() === "delayed";
  }
        
  getImage(): string {
    let basePath = "/assets/images/";
    if (this.airline === "American") {
        return basePath + "aa-logo.png";
    } else if (this.airline === "Delta") {
        return basePath + "delta-logo.png";
    } else if (this.airline === "United") {
        return basePath + "united-logo.png";
    }
    return "";
  }
     
}
```

Comment: what's shows on error

Comment: Move this.getFlights(); from constructor to ngOnInit method of component class.

Comment: this is the part where i get the error it is the one inside the **

import { Flight } from "./flight";

describe('Flight', () => {
 it('should create an instance', () => 
{
   expect**(new Flight())**.toBeTruthy();
});
});

Comment: See my answer below if you have not yet solved this.  You probably need to change `Constructor` to `constructor` (all lowercase).  However, I do recommend you call initialization code in `ngOnInit` instead

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ngOnInit()` function!
Your request is in `constructor()`...

The `constructor()` is the first element executed in a class, and that is one of the reasons **`angular 2`** was created, `angularJS` have this problem, with `ngOnInit()` you can manipulate the sequence of your code.

Please read about **` component life cycle**, is very important to know this concept in profound, otherwise, you will have several issues when your application grows.

```
import {OnInit, etc, etc, etc, } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() {}

      ngOnInit() {
         this.getFlights();
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `AppComponent` you have a method named `Constructor()` which is not called.  You probably meant to make this the class `constructor` with a lowercase `c`

```js
class Foo{
    constructor(){
        console.log('class constructor')
    }

    Constructor(){
        console.log('Constructor method, not called!')
    }
}

const x = new Foo();
```

Comment: constructor is the first element executed in a class

Comment: Yes I know that, but he has made a method called ‘Constructor()’ with a capitol C which is not the same as the class ‘constructor’ which you are talking about

Comment: @Hector, see my edited example above.  Only the standard class `constructor` is called.  The method named `Constructor` is not called since it's different.